# removing margin which browser getting automatically

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When we are creating a web page using bootstrap we can set margins. But web browser also gets some margins. Although code as div(`class="container-fluid"`) or code as `margin:0; and padding:0;` based on the container in the CSS file, I couldn't solve the problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers have a margin on the body tag. Set that to 0 somewhere in your css.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is Browser default margin for body:

**Fix It Like this:**

```
body {
   margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the margin to zero on any element is simple just type something like

```
body{
margin:0
}
```

Although sometimes bootstrap has his own margin rules included like setting margin on h tags, you could remove them as well by using more specific rules ([read about specificity here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)) or by using important

```
h4{
margin: 0 !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is browsers have default styling for elements.

To reset margin only on `body` element you can use:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

To reset **all styling** (which is not so-bad thing) in *all browsers* you can use css library called [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

> Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

This library is used by big companies as GitHub, Twitter, Soundcloud, Guardian, Medium and many others.

Answer (score 1):

Although you put container-fluid, sometimes it doesn't make the width 100% fit the screen because browsers make a default margin and padding.To make it fit the screen you have to do like this.

body{

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

}

If it doesn't work make them important as following.

body{

```
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
```

}